# React-simple-map "Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0"

Tags: json, reactjs

I would like to use react-simple-map for my project in react.

I used the example on github to try to display a simple map :

```
import React, { Component } from "react"
import {
  ComposableMap,
  ZoomableGroup,
  Geographies,
  Geography,
} from "react-simple-maps"

const wrapperStyles = {
  width: "100%",
  maxWidth: 980,
  margin: "0 auto",
}

class BasicMap extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div style={wrapperStyles}>
        <ComposableMap
          projectionConfig={{
            scale: 205,
            rotation: [-11,0,0],
          }}
          width={980}
          height={551}
          style={{
            width: "100%",
            height: "auto",
          }}
          >
          <ZoomableGroup center={[0,20]} disablePanning>
            <Geographies geography="/static/world-50m.json">
              {(geographies, projection) => geographies.map((geography, i) => geography.id !== "ATA" && (
                <Geography
                  key={i}
                  geography={geography}
                  projection={projection}
                  style={{
                    default: {
                      fill: "#ECEFF1",
                      stroke: "#607D8B",
                      strokeWidth: 0.75,
                      outline: "none",
                    },
                    hover: {
                      fill: "#607D8B",
                      stroke: "#607D8B",
                      strokeWidth: 0.75,
                      outline: "none",
                    },
                    pressed: {
                      fill: "#FF5722",
                      stroke: "#607D8B",
                      strokeWidth: 0.75,
                      outline: "none",
                    },
                  }}
                />
              ))}
            </Geographies>
          </ZoomableGroup>
        </ComposableMap>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default BasicMap
```

But, I have the error message "Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0" in the console. I kept exactly the same folders. The only error message is this.

If you have an idea about a map in react, with which i would be able to color each country with different color depending on certains criteria...

Thank you in advance.

Comment: traceback would help

Comment: That suggests that your "JSON" is actually HTML. Look at the data you are getting back from the server. This is the error you get if you do something like JSON.parse("<foo>") -- a JSON string (which you expect with dataType: 'json') cannot begin with <

Answer (score 0):

I faced same problem. If you place world-50m.json inside src folder, react cannot load it with get request - it tries to load it from http://localhost:3000/static/world-50m.json. In my case it returns custom 404 HTML page -> and that is why error "Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0" occurs.

Solution is to move json with map inside react public folder and than it starts to work.